# "Not enough memory" vs. "no enough memory"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs

Which is correct? Why?

- **Not** enough memory
- **No** enough memory

[The first variant](http://www.google.com/search?q="Not+enough+memory%E2%80%9D) seems to be significantly more popular on the Internet than the [second one](http://www.google.com/search?q="No+enough+memory%E2%80%9D).

I want to use such construction as an error message in the program. I think it is a short version of the sentence "There is not enough memory".

Comment: The second one sounds plain wrong to me.

Comment: @MadWard I think that it is wrong, too. But why? I can't find any good reference.

Comment: This site right here is a good reference. And here is what this site right here has to say: "No enough" is not English. No native speaker would ever use it, ever, at all.

Comment: Consider, "Insufficient memory" [for this operation]

Comment: @ЯegDwight Google Ngram Viewer shows [small statistics on 'no enough' phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+enough&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20enough%3B%2Cc0). Is it full of mistakes and typos?

Comment: I would say "not enough memory" ... the second answer does not sound good to me. I never heard anyone say "no enough memory"

Comment: @Constructor: Some of those hits appear to be typos. Others are false hits due to punctuation between the two words (such as,  _**No**, **enough** was never enough for his brother,_ and, _**No**! **Enough** of this arguing_). Others are found where an entire passage was written as if it were colloquial speech (e.g., _There's a lot of lowing and no' enough sewing goin' on here_).

Comment: ***No** enough memory* is not at all correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*No* goes in front of nouns to negate them, and *not* goes in front of adjectives or phrases to negate them.  Not the other way around.

This is one of English's less flexible rules.  The second sentence sounds very wrong.

Comment: @Constructor wait. What about this sentence - "*it's no big deal.*?

Comment: The additional answer that mentions a determiner explains this.  The determiner of a noun, which is a type of adjective, always comes first, then adjectives that modify the noun, then the noun.  So in *no big deal*, *no* is the determiner of (and modifies) *deal*, not *big.*  Think of "no" as in the same category of words as articles.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of the Noun Phrase you quoted is like this -

> (Modifier + Determiner) + Head Noun

**Head Noun** -> *Memory*

**Determiner** -> *Enough*

**Modifier of determiner** -> *Not*

*Not* here is an adverb and it functions as a modifier of determiner - *enough*. The word - *no* - can't function like that. *No* itself is a determiner.

So here the correct Noun Phrase would be - **Not enough memory**. Using *no* in place of *not* is plain wrong.

Now one problem is there. If you are the one who determines the parts of speech of a word from dictionary, you might get confused looking at the entry of **enough** in various dictionaries, online or offline. Because some dictionary says this particular word a determiner, some says it's an adjective. And some says it's both. And my answer says it's a determiner. So who is right and who is wrong. If it's an adjective, and not a determiner my answer is wrong, because my answer is based on the conclusion that **enough** is a determiner, not an adjective. We will see the reason behind my claim that it's a determiner.

One thing that I have learned from here, and that's a very important lesson is that dictionary is never a place to look for the parts of speech of a word.

**enough** - *Adjective* or *determiner*?

- *Enough* can come before an adjective in a NP structure like a determiner.
- *Enough* is not gradable.
- *Enough* can take place in partitive construction - *We have **enough of gun power***.

So I concluded taking whatever is written above that **enough** is a *determiner*.

<sub>My another answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/86301/3463) says more about it.</sub>