# Can I use "No, at all" instead of not at all"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> When we were asked, "Would you mind...?" we answered, "No, not at all."

But can I use "no at all" instead of "not at all?"

Comment: This might help - [“Not enough memory” vs. “no enough memory”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/95217/1423)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. "No at all" sounds super strange in this case. I don't think it is common idiomatic use. Here is some data on the matter.
[image]

My advice: just use "not at all".

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I really appreciate it.