# Determiner, Adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective-phrases

Context: She has known him for more than ten years.

In the above mentioned sentence, every word can separately be analyzed grammatically. For example:

1. She is a subject / pronoun.
2. has + known = present perfect tense
3. him is an object / pronoun.
4. for more than is a prepositional phrase.
5. What is "ten"? Determiner/ Adjective?
6. Years is a noun.

In order to understand grammar in detail, I am trying to focus on the usage of words in different contexts.

Regards

Comment: The cardinal numbers like "ten" are determiners (or more precisely determinatives). The preposition phrase is the whole sequence "for more than ten years".

Comment: This answer would be helpful http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/86301/3463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to split a sentence *directly* into words, it's often more instructive to break it down into *phrases*, each of which breaks down further. This lets us see the overall structure better.

For example, consider something like "tenth birthday card". *Tenth* is an adjective, and *birthday* and *card* are both nouns; but the phrase can mean either "card for someone's tenth birthday" (with *tenth* modifying *birthday*, and *tenth birthday* modifying *card*) or "tenth card for someone's birthday" (with *birthday* modifying *card*, and *tenth* modifying *birthday card*). If we focus too narrowly on individual words, we won't see this ambiguity.

One useful tool is a parse tree, which lets us visualize the structure. For example, we might parse your sentence something like this:

[image: [example parse tree]]

As you can see, the object of *for* is actually *more than ten years* (not just *more than*); and I've classified the numeral *ten* as a *quantifier* (following the terminology of the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*), though you could also call it a *determiner*, *specifier*, *determinative*, *adjective*, or even *noun*.

(Note: even setting aside terminology, the structure shown in the above parse tree is not the only possible analysis. A lot of the details are debatable, there are different schools of thought, etc.; but it should give you a sense of how to think about syntax.)

Comment: What an explanation! ruakh I thank you for your sincere efforts. Regards